# importing html file (and all the stylesheets and scripts) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

is there any way to import an external html file, with all the linked css and javascript files, to an already existing html document?

I have tried with JQuery method [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), but it seems it is ignoring scripts completely.

Basically, what I am trying to do is to load a complete component, with its style and logic/behavior.

I need to do this on the client side, with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something you might be able to use an iframe for. An iframe will load an entirely different document inside a dom element.

```
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid using iframe, but that is indeed one of the solutions.